# How is "$foo = 5 && $bar = 15" evaluated, and why is it not a error?

Tags: php, operator-precedence, associativity

Let's say we got a simple code like this:

```
// $foo and $bar aren't defined before

$foo = 5 && $bar = 15;

// var_dump()
// $foo is (bool) TRUE
// $bar is (int) 15
```

so I assume it works like:

```
$foo = (5 && ($bar = 15))
```

but in my opinion it should be:

```
$foo = ((5 && $bar) = 15) // should throw syntax error due FALSE = 15
```

1. evaluation form left to right [$foo want 5 but && is higher]
2. && got the highest priority [so && takes 5 and $bar]

   - 5 == TRUE; $bar == Undefined [so it's NULL == FALSE]
3. = got the right associativity [waits for evaluation of (5 && $bar)]

Please explain it in easiest way (on some other examples) to poor man like me. Regards.

Comment: In your example you're assigning, not comparing.

Comment: Could You post step by step of this assignment?

Comment: I've answered my best

Comment: There is a parse error because there is no `;`.  Once you fix that there is a parse error because `$foo = FALSE = 15` is not valid.

Comment: $foo = 5 && $bar = 15; is 100% valid and I want to know why PHP prcoesses it in way $foo = (5 && ($bar = 15)) ... why not in $foo = ((5 && $bar) = 15) to throw an error... I want to know what's going in the hood when processing $foo = 5 && $bar = 15;

Comment: I understand this question because [`&&` has higher precedence than assignments](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think reading the manual page here helps and clears a lot of things.

So how does this get's evaluated?

```
$foo = 5 && $bar = 15;
```

First you have to know that `&&` has a higher precedence than `=`. So the first thought would be this:

```
$foo = (5 && $bar) = 15;
```

But now is the point where you have to read the manual until the end: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

And a quote from there:

> **Note:**
>   Although = has a lower precedence than most other operators, PHP will still allow expressions similar to the following: if (!$a = foo()), in which case the return value of foo() is put into $a.

What does that mean?

It silently assign 15 to `$bar` e.g.

```
$foo = (5 && ($bar = 15));
```

Now you can evaluate `&&`, `$bar` get's assigned with 15 and `5 && 15` is TRUE and get's assign to `$foo`

Comment: OK, so my problem is just an exception to the rule :-) @Rizier123 I didn't understand this 'note' in PHP manual now I do, thanks :-)

Comment: @firstandlastpost You're welcome! Have a nice day :D (FYI: If you didn't already saw it you can take a tour here: http://stackoverflow.com/tour and see how this site works :D (Welcome on SO!))

Answer (score 0):

Lets dissect your line of code:

```
 $foo = 5 && $bar = 15;
```

First I'd like to point out that = is an assignment operator, and generally will return true.

That being said, this breaks down as follows:

```
$foo = (5 && ($bar = 15))
$foo = (5 && (true))
$foo = ( (true) && (true) )
$foo = (true)
$foo = true
```

&& stands for AND and compares two booleans, returning true if both are true, false if otherwise. Note that the assignment of $bar = 15 will return true, and in the case of 5, that non-zero integers also return true.

Comment: so the assignment operator has precedence over &&?

Comment: Its read from left to right. The first = is evaluated, but it can't evaluate until the right side is evaluated. So 5 && $bar = 15 needs to be evaluated. Next operator is &&, which needs 5 and $bar=15 to be evaluated. 5 evaluates to true and $bar=15 evaluates to true, then  && evals to true and now the right side of the first = evals to true, assigning true to $foo.

Comment: IMHO the && operator needs 5 and $bar.. so 5 (TRUE) and $bar (Undefined == NULL). Why PHP takes $bar = 15 if in documentation it says that && has higher precedence than =?

Comment: @firstandlastpost You're exactly right :D There is even a Note for this in the manual if you read it until the end